# PHP & MySQL - Update Query not updating database

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I'm making a personal website and I just wanted it to be a bit easier for me to add/edit my posts without manually going into phpmyadmin.

When I go to the edit_post.php page and press update I get an "=" sign next to the pid eg.(foo.php?pid=3), and if i let it redirect to the blog page it doesn't update it.

**Blog page**

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include_once("../IncBlog/db.php");
?>
<?php include "../Includes/navHead.php"; ?>
  <title>Adam Brickhill - Life Journal </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="header">
    <nav class="nav"><p class="title"><a class="postLink" href="../IncBlog/post.php">- Lone Tree -</a></p></nav>
   </div>
   <!-- JOURNAL !-->
   <?php
    require_once("../nbbc/nbbc.php");

    $bbcode = new BBCode;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";

    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    $posts = "";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      $id =   $row['id'];
      $title =  $row['title'];
      $img =   $row['img'];
      $content =  $row['content'];
      $date =  $row['date'];

      $admin = "<div><a href='../IncBlog/del_post.php?pid$id'>Delete</a>&nbsp;<div><a href='../IncBlog/edit_post.php?pid$id'>Edit</a>";

      $output = $bbcode->Parse($content);

      ob_start();
       include('../IncBlog/blogSkel.php');
       $posts .= ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
     }
     echo $posts;
    }
    else {
     echo "There are no posts to display";
    }
   ?>
   <div class="journal">
    <div class="catagories">
    
    </div>
    <!-- Date !-->
    <!-- Picture !-->
    <!-- Description !-->
   </div>
   

   <?php include "../Includes/navFooter.php"; ?>
   <!-- SCRIPTS !-->
   <?php include "../Includes/navScriptImport.php"; ?>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Edit Page**

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include_once("db.php");

 if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header("Location: login.php");
  return;
 }

 $pid = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $pid = trim($pid, "/IncBlog/edit_post.php?pid");

 $pid = strip_tags($pid);
 $pid = stripslashes($pid);
 $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $pid);
 //echo "$pid";

 if ($pid == "") {
  header("Location: ../Nav/life.php");
 }

 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
  $content = strip_tags($_POST['content']);
  $img = strip_tags($_POST['image']);

  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $title);
  $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content);
  $img = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $img);

  $date = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");

  $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', content='$content', img='$img', date='$date' WHERE id=$pid";

  if ($title == "" || $content == "") {
   echo "The database is hungry you can't feed it nothing!";
   return;
  }

  mysqli_query($db, $sql);

  header("Location: ../Nav/life.php");
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Blog - Post</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
   $sql_get = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$pid LIMIT 1";
   $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql_get);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     $title = $row['title'];
     $content = $row['content'];
     $img = $row['image'];

     echo "<form action='edit_post.php?pid=$pid' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
     echo " <input placeholder='Title' type='text' name='title' value='$title' autofocus size='48'><br /><br />";
     echo " <input placeholder='Image' type='text' name='image' value='$img' autofocus size='48'><br /><br />";
     echo " <textarea placeholder='Content' name='content' rows='40' cols='40'>$content</textarea><br />";
    }
   }
  ?>

  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to check for errors via php and the queries, you're not doing that. and var_dump the ID and other variables

Comment: I already have, The ID is 1 and the PID is 1 click update and nothing happens.

Comment: I removed RESOLVED from the title in an edit. If an answer posted below solved it, then accept one. If none haven't, then you can post your own answer. Accepting an answer automatically tells the system that the question was solved; no further action on your part is required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the columns and set the values for the columns.

```
UPDATE posts SET ( title, content, img, date ) VALUES ($title, $content, $img, $date) WHERE id = $pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
```

use instead of above line

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime());

$sql = 'UPDATE posts SET title='".$title."', content='".$content."', img='".$img."', date='".$date."' WHERE id='".$pid."'";
```

Comment: Nope didn't work either, both dates work. That's not my issue, the issue is when I click update to update a post it doesn't apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out, very small programmers blindness but hey we all get it.

Line 66 `echo "<form action='edit_post.php?pid$pid' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";`
Where it says "?pid$pid" I just needed to remove the "=" that i had there.